# SQL Server on Linux not working after reboot, SSL errors

Tags: sql-server, linux, ssl

I realized I only had 12GB of RAM in my server running my SQL Server instance, so I powered down and added RAM and powered back up. Ever since it rebooted, the SQL Server service will not start and stay started. Log is below. I don't have any SSL certs (I know, really stupid of me) installed for this instance as it's just a local instance for right now, so I'm not sure why I'm getting SSL cert-related errors on service startup. Any ideas?

`/var/opt/mssql/mssql.conf`:

```
[sqlagent]
enabled = false

[licensing]
azurebilling = false

[EULA]
accepteula = Y
```

log file:

```
2023-04-23 22:29:01.61 Server      Microsoft SQL Server 2022 (RTM-CU3) (KB5024396) - 16.0.4025.1 (X64) 
    Mar 13 2023 19:10:08 
    Copyright (C) 2022 Microsoft Corporation
    Developer Edition (64-bit) on Linux (Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS) <X64>
2023-04-23 22:29:01.62 Server      UTC adjustment: 0:00
2023-04-23 22:29:01.62 Server      (c) Microsoft Corporation.
2023-04-23 22:29:01.62 Server      All rights reserved.
2023-04-23 22:29:01.62 Server      Server process ID is 556.
2023-04-23 22:29:01.62 Server      Logging SQL Server messages in file '/var/opt/mssql/log/errorlog'.
2023-04-23 22:29:01.63 Server      Registry startup parameters: 
     -d /var/opt/mssql/data/master.mdf
     -l /var/opt/mssql/data/mastlog.ldf
     -e /var/opt/mssql/log/errorlog
2023-04-23 22:29:01.64 Server      SQL Server detected 2 sockets with 4 cores per socket and 8 logical processors per socket, 16 total logical processors; using 16 logical processors based on SQL Server licensing. This is an informational message; no user action is required.
2023-04-23 22:29:01.64 Server      SQL Server is starting at normal priority base (=7). This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
2023-04-23 22:29:01.65 Server      Detected 19259 MB of RAM. This is an informational message; no user action is required.
2023-04-23 22:29:01.65 Server      Using conventional memory in the memory manager.
2023-04-23 22:29:01.65 Server      Detected pause instruction latency: 24 cycles.
2023-04-23 22:29:01.67 Server      Page exclusion bitmap is enabled.
2023-04-23 22:29:01.72 Server      Buffer pool extension is not supported on Linux platform.
2023-04-23 22:29:01.74 Server      Buffer Pool: Allocating 4194304 bytes for 2985785 hashPages.
2023-04-23 22:29:01.97 Server      Buffer pool extension is already disabled. No action is necessary.
2023-04-23 22:29:02.64 Server      Installing Client TLS certificates to the store.
2023-04-23 22:29:02.65 Server      Error searching first file in /var/opt/mssql/security/ca-certificates: 3(The system cannot find the path specified.)
```

The output of `ls /var/opt/mssql`:

```
data  log  mssql.conf  secrets
```

`UPDATE`: I followed [this guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-encrypted-connections?view=sql-server-ver16) and [this guide "SQL Server on Linux support"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/backup-restore/sql-server-backup-to-url-s3-compatible-object-storage-best-practices-and-troubleshooting?view=sql-server-ver16) and created a self-signed cert and placed it in `/var/opt/mssql/security/ca-certificates` and I'm still receiving the same error.

`UPDATE 2`: It's now reading the SSL cert, it seems, but still failing to start and now I don't actually know what the error is because the `errorlog` file doesn't show any errors. Log file is below.

```
2023-04-25 12:16:25.08 Server      Microsoft SQL Server 2022 (RTM-CU3) (KB5024396) - 16.0.4025.1 (X64) 
    Mar 13 2023 19:10:08 
    Copyright (C) 2022 Microsoft Corporation
    Express Edition (64-bit) on Linux (Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS) <X64>
2023-04-25 12:16:25.08 Server      UTC adjustment: 0:00
2023-04-25 12:16:25.08 Server      (c) Microsoft Corporation.
2023-04-25 12:16:25.08 Server      All rights reserved.
2023-04-25 12:16:25.09 Server      Server process ID is 556.
2023-04-25 12:16:25.09 Server      Logging SQL Server messages in file '/var/opt/mssql/log/errorlog'.
2023-04-25 12:16:25.09 Server      Registry startup parameters: 
     -d /var/opt/mssql/data/master.mdf
     -l /var/opt/mssql/data/mastlog.ldf
     -e /var/opt/mssql/log/errorlog
2023-04-25 12:16:25.10 Server      SQL Server detected 2 sockets with 4 cores per socket and 8 logical processors per socket, 16 total logical processors; using 8 logical processors based on SQL Server licensing. This is an informational message; no user action is required.
2023-04-25 12:16:25.10 Server      SQL Server is starting at normal priority base (=7). This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
2023-04-25 12:16:25.11 Server      Detected 19259 MB of RAM. This is an informational message; no user action is required.
2023-04-25 12:16:25.11 Server      Using conventional memory in the memory manager.
2023-04-25 12:16:25.11 Server      Detected pause instruction latency: 24 cycles.
2023-04-25 12:16:25.11 Server      Page exclusion bitmap is enabled.
2023-04-25 12:16:25.15 Server      Buffer pool extension is not supported on Linux platform.
2023-04-25 12:16:25.16 Server      Buffer Pool: Allocating 4194304 bytes for 2984885 hashPages.
2023-04-25 12:16:25.37 Server      Buffer pool extension is already disabled. No action is necessary.
2023-04-25 12:16:26.04 Server      Installing Client TLS certificates to the store.
2023-04-25 12:16:26.06 Server      Successfully placed mssql.crt in trusted root store
2023-04-25 12:16:26.06 Server      Number of Files Processed in /var/opt/mssql/security/ca-certificates directory: 1
```

Comment: SQL Server generally creates its own self-signed certificate during installation. On Linux platforms SQL Server uses the OpenSSL libraries, did you just upgrade (or completely remove) those before the reboot?

Comment: `Error searching first file in /var/opt/mssql/security/ca-certificates:` ... What do you get for `find /var/opt/mssql/ -type f`? Please edit your question and add the output ...

Comment: @AlwaysLearning I haven't touched any SSL libraries whatsoever. I just did an `apt update` and `apt-get upgrade`  and rebooted, and this started happening.

Comment: @tink It displays a whole boatload of log files, my databases, the system .hiv files, et cetera but does not output any security certs or anything like that.

Comment: Is it missing the cert files or the whole directory?

Comment: @tink There is no directory for certs whatsoever in `/var/opt/mssql`

Comment: Check if the user `mssql` has access to the folder.

Comment: @Max even with `sudo chown -R mssql:mssql /var/opt/mssql` I get the same error.

Comment: Did you solve the issue? I have the same problem, when I reboot linux, for some reason the service stops but it works fine if I run the service manually immediately  after rebooting.